# Adapt translation of "available" for Outlook Calendar system wide, e.g. via Exchange Server?

Tags: outlook, exchange, localization

I want to change a single string (translation/resource) in the Outlook Calendar. 
The default Calendar-status "available" in Dutch is called **"vrij"** by Outlook.
The Outlook usage would translate as **"available**", but usually "vrij" in Dutch is used as "time off" (meaning **"unavailable"**)!
(FWIW: the Calendar-status "unavailable" in Dutch is "niet aanwezig".)

A lot of my colleagues do not notice that the default value "vrij" means "available", so they leave their unavailable times marked as "available".
Of course, we could try to teach this to everybody, but I would prefer to prevent the confusion in the first place.
So it would be nice if we could change the resource string system wide, e.g. via Exchange Server.

An alternative approach (work around) might be to change the default Calendar-status when creating a new Calendar item.
I think it leaves some room for confusion (the confusing value is still there), 
but at least the confusing value would not be the default, and might be clearer when contrasted by the other pull-down values.
It seems possible to individually [change the default Outlook Calendar status through a form](http://www.ehow.com/how_6871574_do-_amp_-busy-outlook-calendar_.html),
but would it also be possible to do this system wide?  (And would this be acceptable, would this overwrite their own forms, e.g. [defaulting appointments to private](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/677), or would this overwrite just this single value?)

---

PS: I posted this on StackOverflow first, but I guess it is not really a programmer-question, but more for network administrators.  (I am a programmer, not a system administrator, but I would like to present him a 'ready made' solution.)